# Recursive interface with predefined items and unknown items

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I am trying to create an interface, but I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error and how to resolve it.

> Property `'_a'` of type `'IItem | IItem[] | undefined'` is not assignable to string index type `'{ _sub1?: any; _sub2?: any; _sub3?: any; }'`

This is the interface that I am using:

```
export interface IItem {
  _a?: IItem | IItem[];
  _b?: IItem | IItem[];
  [key: string]: {
    _sub1?: any;
    _sub2?: any;
    _sub3?: boolean;
    [key: string]: IItem;
  }
}
```

Here is the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSX1QFs4BvAKDjgH1MB%20ALgKOFIB8WSBtAXQG4qtAEZMubOJ0I8BQ7gGtgAT2YBnGFGQBzXs0rVqNVQFdhARjGYkSwQdonhAJkvXbBo6YDMY4RAgAbYCs3agVlNQ1tXXFiNwBfCjigA)

Comment: how is this a javascript related question though ?

Comment: `type A = {
  a: string;
};

type B = A & { [k: string]: boolean };`

Answer (score 2):

You should create  a separate type for the  'fixed' keys part and the 'generic' string type, than use the union `&` operator:

```
type IItemFixedKeys = {
  _a?: IItem | IItem[];
  _b?: IItem | IItem[];
}  

type IItemGenericKeys = { 
  [key: string]: {
    _sub1?: any;
    _sub2?: any;
    _sub3?: any;
  }
}

export type IItem =  IItemFixedKeys & IItemGenericKeys

const x: IItem  = {
  _a: { // Error: Type '{ _sub1: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IItem | IItem[] | undefined'.
    _sub1: 'test'
  },

  _c: { // Works perfectly, because _a is not a 'fixed' key
    _sub1: 'test'
  }
}
```

[Playground reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkjwQLYDECWAPCATA0hEAzlALxQDeAsAFBRQD6AhgPwBcs8SUAPuwogNoBdANzVadAEatenHnD5DRVAL61q1UJBmIA4hAB2EAE6oAxnkIlyUMVH4BrfGwLAT+gOaC2lGrXoEAVwkARmkGfRAlP38ggCYwiKi-OkCJAGYEyNtlahyqagh0MAB7I2AoTWh5TlJtNExcfCIAMm09QxNzJvV8qlNi-RcodDZqxFpSH3EGb1txVOC2AHIEFyXsgBoe8VNZ33mgxagViDXs3KA)

---

As noted in the comments, this solution has some problems. Another (better) option is to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types):

```
type FixedKeys =  '_a' | '_b'
type IItem = { 
  [key: string]: typeof key extends FixedKeys ? IItem | IItem[] : {
    _sub1?: any;
    _sub2?: any;
    _sub3?: boolean;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAMQJYA8YBMDSMIGc4C8ccA5APoCGJcAPqWQEYmiSxwCS7YMAtoXAG84oYgG0A1jgBccXGABOSAHYBzALozWMAPYAzOJIhwYKbkvT5kaLDnwB+Dl161H3HqLVwZAkcThlcAFcGAEY7GQolCABuX2IA4IAmcLhImLj-IIYAZhSGbW0AGxhI2JBiAF9QKpBQAGNtJTk4CBlON2IiH3L-Ou8MhNCZEm45Zh6amvrG5pQ2pz5+bviKGQgAGlBfMj7BAayQ4dGwccrqoA)

Comment: If you see my changes, I changed `_sub3` to a `boolean` and added `[key: string]: IItem;`. This gives an error. Any fix for that?

Comment: Interesting, but we can't construct the final IItem. Can you help with that? See example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkjwQLYDECWAPCATA0hEAzlALxQDeAsAFBRQD6AhgPwBcs8SUAPuwogNoBdANzVadAEatenHnD5DRVAL61q1UJBmIA4hAB2EAE6oAxnkIlyUMVH4BrfGwLAT+gOaC2lGrXoEAVwkARmkGfRAlP38ggCYwiKi-OkCJAGYEyNtlahyqagh0MAB7I2AoTWh5TlJtNExcfCIAMm09QxNzJvUqU2L9FygQNmrEWlIfcVNvW3FU4LYAcgQXRezcnr6B8vQRjjGrSfoGNhAAGh6pmd85oIWoZYhV9ZUgA

Comment: I don't see any problem @Anton , the playground only complains that `x` is not used

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn what do you mean `[key: string]: IItem;` ? You can't have multiple `[key:string]: Type` entries in the same  type

Comment: @gbalduzzi I've added console.log to show the error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkjwQLYDECWAPCATA0hEAzlALxQDeAsAFBRQD6AhgPwBcs8SUAPuwogNoBdANzVadAEatenHnD5DRVAL61q1UJBmIA4hAB2EAE6oAxnkIlyUMVH4BrfGwLAT+gOaC2lGrXoEAVwkARmkGfRAlP38ggCYwiKi-OkCJAGYEyNtlahyqagh0MAB7I2AoTWh5TlJtNExcfCIAMm09QxNzJvUqU2L9FygQNmrEWlIfcVNvW3FU4LYAcgQXRezcnr6B8vQRjjGrSfoGNhAAGh6pmd85oIWoZYhV9ZVN-oJigBsIADpP4vcAAp0ABKYRAA

Comment: @gbalduzzi Hmmm. It compiles and runs, but it shows error in editor only. I'm slightly confused.

Comment: Yeah I found the error now. I'm actually confused, this does not seem like a situation typescript enjoys

Comment: @gbalduzzi wow. Elegant. I like it, but maybe not the topic starter, because his interface is deeper :)

Comment: You just need to repeat the conditional trick at the nested level

Comment: It is just missing a way for `[key: string]...` to reference `IItem` again.

Comment: @gbalduzzi I've tried to make another level of conditional typecast, but I've broken :) can you take a look? link: https://shorturl.at/qAMS9

Answer (score 1):

> Property '_a' of type 'IItem | IItem[] | undefined' is not assignable
> to string index type '{ _sub1?: any; _sub2?: any; _sub3?: any; }'

You get this error because string index "see" all the fields of interface, so they all should be of the same type. Example:

```js
export interface IItem {
  _a?: IItem | IItem[];
  _b?: IItem | IItem[];
  [key: string]: IItem | IItem[] | undefined;
}
```

But if you will use number index, then you do not have such restriction:

```js
export interface IItem {
  _a?: IItem | IItem[];
  _b?: IItem | IItem[];
  [key: number]: IItem | IItem[] | undefined;
  anotherElement: any;
}
```

or:

```js
export interface IItem {
  _a?: IItem | IItem[];
  _b?: IItem | IItem[];
  [key: number]: {
    _sub1?: any;
    _sub2?: any;
    _sub3?: any;
  }
}
```

P.S. You've just updated your question, but the problem is the same:

```js
export interface IItem {
  _a?: IItem | IItem[];
  _b?: IItem | IItem[];
  [key: string]: {
    _sub1?: any;
    _sub2?: any;
    _sub3?: boolean;
    [key: string]: IItem; // <--- it expects that _sub1..3 will be of type IItem
  }
}
```

P.P.S. I've used this page: [click](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/indexable-types.html).

Comment: So this fixes the issue, with the outer `[key: ...]`, but the inner one doesn't work now. I changed it to a number as well and works in the interface, but then the javascript doesn't work.